# Failed to connect to MySQL localhost server Win32Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, database-connection, wampserver

I am trying to connect to the database from simple console-application (C#) to localhost that is running from **WAMP** server. I have tried with **multiple** string Connections but neider works

usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using  System.Data.SqlClient;
using  System.Data.Sql;
```

code:

```
 public void ConnectToSQLDataBase()
        {
            SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;database=sys;password=root");
            conn.Open();
        }
```

I have tried to connect to the dataBase via server explorer and it gives me no trouble. I have used the connection string that I found under the properties of a database in service explorer but I've got the same [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOsBA.png)

The database is running on WAMP: MySql - Host: 127.0.0.1 port: 3306 user: root password: root, and it is the only database on the server.

I am running out of ideas !?

Comment: use the mysql connector https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/ what you are using works only with ms sql server https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers

Comment: thank you! .. I have install  **MySql.Data** from nuget and changed sqlConnection to **MySqlConnection** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved the problem !

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

  public void ConnectToSQLDataBase()
        {

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;database=sys;password=root");
            conn.Open();
        }
```